# array indexing not working properly

Tags: php, arrays

Hey guys i have tried to add the key of an array to another array's key but i didnt get the output as i expected ..My code is

```
<?php

$some = array('anna'=>'2','revathy'=>'baba');

$honey = array_keys($some);


$something = array();



foreach($honey as $value) {

$something[$value]=$some[$value];


echo $something[$value];

 }

?>
```

When i run this code it shows blank screen  instead of the output ..Hope you guys can help me out ..Any help would be appreaciated..

Comment: What is $v in echo $something[$v];

Comment: You both use `$value` and `$v` for indexing `$something` variable in the foreach.

Comment: sorry i have redited the code ..please check it now

Comment: what is your expected output.... please be more specific on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `array_keys` returns something like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'anna' (length=4)
  1 => string 'revathy' (length=7)
```

So, what you need to do to make your script work is like this:

*p.s. in your script you had an undefined variable `$v`*

```
<?php

$some = array('anna'=>'2','revathy'=>'baba');

$honey = array_keys($some);

$something = array();

foreach($honey as $key => $value) // this is the change
{
    $something[$value] = $some[$value];

    echo $something[$value] ."<br>"; // and here
}
```

Outputs:

```
2
baba
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me ...i have acceoted your answer ..but i have one doubt remaining when i used $key instead of $value ..i get blank output ..can you tell me why it is like that..

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($honey as $key => $value) {
    $something[$key]=$value;
}
```

This is the proper way of dong this :)
There is absolutely no need for $honey = array_keys($some);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that to copy an array with php. The equal operator copies it unless you use the reference operator (`= &$some`).

The only thing you have to do is :

```
<?php

$some = array('anna'=>'2','revathy'=>'baba');
$something = $some;

?>
```

And to additionally print it :

```
echo implode(', ', array_values($something));
```

Answer (score -1):

change $v to $value, it's working for me

Comment: for me the problem still exist ..what output did you get ?

Comment: I get 2baba, you can also use var_dump() instead of echo if it's for testing, you have more information then

Answer (score -2):

you can skip

```
$honey = array_keys($some);
```

just do

```
foreach($some as $key => $value)
{
    $something[$key] = $value;
}
```